# Custom button bar on jquery date picker not visible on manual input change

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have added a custom button to the datepicker using datepicker.setdefaults
Everything is working fine but only issue is when the date is entered from the keyboard by user the custom button bar on the datepicker disappears. Can some one help. Below is the code.

$.datepicker.setDefaults({
        firstDay: 1,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths:true,
        selectOtherMonths:true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        maxDate:new Date('12/26/9999'),

```
beforeShow: function( input ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var buttonPane = $( input )
                .datepicker( "widget")
                .find( ".ui-datepicker-buttonpane" );
            var btn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">End of Time</button>');
           btn.unbind("click").bind("click", function() {
               $(input).datepicker('setDate', new Date(endOfTime));
           //    $(input).datepicker('hide');
               $(input).trigger('change');
           });
            btn.appendTo( buttonPane );
        }, 0);
    },

    onChangeMonthYear: function( year, month, instance ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var buttonPane = $( instance.input )
                .datepicker( "widget" )
                .find( ".ui-datepicker-buttonpane" );

            var btn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">End of Time</button>');

            btn.unbind("click").bind("click", function() {

                $(instance.input).datepicker('setDate', new Date(endOfTime));
             //   $(instance.input).datepicker('hide');
                $(instance.input).trigger('change');
            });


            btn.appendTo( buttonPane );

        }, 0 );
    }

});
```